do-release-upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 deleted systemd-resolved
I got a warning during the upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 that deleting systemd-resolved would create name resolution problems (no kidding).
Having completed the upgrade to 24.04, I now have no ability to resolve queries. The obvious solution would be to reinstall systemd-resolved; but apt fails because it cannot resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'. (chicken-->egg-->chicken) I managed to workaround that by adding a temporary entry in /etc/hosts:
91.189.91.83   us.archive.ubuntu.com
But now apt is failing because it can't resolve 'proxy'. Temporary failure resolving 'proxy' I have no proxy configured and there is no host by that name.
What do I need to do to just get systemd-resolved installed?
Or is there new resolver for 24.04 that I need to enable?
Why did do-release-upgrade uninstall it and not replace it?

24.04 is still in beta so this is off topic. You should report a bug as part of the testing process

A package systemd-resolved has never existed in 22.04, first release it existed is 23.04, so the package has not been removed during release upgrade.

Did you read the list of known issues on that process... The process is closed due to those issues; and the list of issues should have been warning enough I'd have thought.  The initial release of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (which hasn't happened yet) is for NEW INSTALLS only... with work on the release-upgrade process (that is occurring now, but its not priority yet) being scheduled for next, so it can be opened from 23.10 to 24.04 on the week (or two) post-release, then after that's completed the 22.04 to 24.04 upgrade in the following weeks (that doesn't open till 24.04.1 anyway).

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-24-04-release-status-tracking/44043  Note: blockers are major bugs, other less-serious bugs are also tracked elsewhere

I can confirm this problem also for the final version of (K)Ubuntu 24.04. In my case the release upgarde from 22.04 failed at some point. But fortunately I was able to finish the upgrade somhow. It turned out that sudo dpkg -i systemd-resolved_255.4-1ubuntu8_amd64.deb finally fixed the main problem of the not working DNS name resolution. So in the end this is a valid question and it shouldn't be down-voted.

@Clemens: bingo! Totally agree with you. And for a version that was still not released as non-beta but in a state were Canonical itself provides an upgrade path to the final release version, it's ridiculous and rather unwelcoming the way this was handled. Voting to reopen. One of the reasons I moved on to Unix.SE long ago.

I have a successful workaround.
Download .deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/systemd-resolved/download and install directly.
Now I have working name resolution again.
One method to download with dysfunctional name resolution and curl would be to use something like this:
curl -L --doh-url https://9.9.9.9/dns-query -O $URL

where -L makes curl follow location headers (redirects) and --do-url tells it to do name resolution via the Quad9 DNS. A possible alternative would be --resolve 'somename.tld:80:[::1]' (IPv6) or --resolve 'somename.tld:80:10.0.0.1' (IPv4) to sidestep system name resolution for a single request.

How did you get systemd-resolved working after you installed it? I managed to install it manually, and sudo service systemd-resolved status says it's running, but ping https://www.google.com still gives "Name or service not known." I've set a DNS server in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/[WHATEVER].conf, and it shows up in the "Global" DNS server list given by resolvectl status.

@Vectornaut Sorry. Having installed it, it just worked. I probably rebooted.

Thanks for clarifying! After posting my earlier comment, I discovered that apt was somehow able to download from software repositories, even though I never saw ping work. In other words, when it came to apt, installing systemd-resolved by hand just worked for me too. If you never tried to ping a URL, maybe our experiences are consistent.

In my case, the necessary setting in /etc/systemd/resolve.conf was not set. That is, no DNS server was configured, at all.
Setting it fixed it for me.
